# Does WordPress API support Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

Having browsed the official [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) site - and looking at the various endpoints - I cannot find information of custom post types. I appreciate there is the [WordPress REST API Plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) that appears to add support for CPT's - but does the official API support them?

If not - is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same doubt about Wordpress Rest API and I also read the Wordpress rest API docs. If you want to create custom post type using Rest API then you can use this plugin [Wordpress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/). In this plugin you just need to create function in controller folder ( posts.php ) make sure your auth should be on, for that you can use [json-api-user](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/).